# Give me Attribute error using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

They show me error that `You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element` these is page link https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille?view=entries

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
base_url='https://www.avocats-lille.com/'
url = 'https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille?view=entries'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
tra = soup.find_all('h2',class_='title')
productlinks=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=base_url+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)
        
for link in productlinks:
    driver.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    tel=soup.select('.address+ .contact p').text
    email=soup.select('.contact a').text
    print(tel,email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS selectors strategy

`soup.select_one('.contact + div > p:nth-child(1) > span > a')`

will extract the emails

and

```
soup.select_one('.address+ .contact p')
```

will grab the telephone numbers only.

**Full working code as an example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= s, options=options)
base_url='https://www.avocats-lille.com/'
url = 'https://www.avocats-lille.com/fr/annuaire/avocats-du-tableau-au-barreau-de-lille?view=entries'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
tra = soup.find_all('h2',class_='title')
productlinks=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=base_url+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)
        
for link in productlinks:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    t=soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Tél.")')
    tel = t.next_element.replace('Tél.', '').strip() if t else None
    mail=soup.select_one('.contact + div > p:nth-child(1) > span > a')
    email = mail.text if mail else None
    print(tel,email)
```

**Output:**

```
03 28 07 30 11 kamelabbas2002@yahoo.fr
03 28 36 94 42 fzabdellatif@2MZA-avocats.com
03 59 09 68 95 charlesabeel.avocat@gmail.com
03 20 74 98 81 laboucaya@gmx.fr
03 20 74 22 33 robertadam@cabinet-squillaci.fr
03 20 54 81 55 contact@agba-avocat.com
06 31 20 89 94 alessi.avocat@gmail.com
03 20 02 98 60 alibacha.avocat@yahoo.fr
06 33 34 28 04 julie@allain-avocat.com
03 20 21 45 45 nicolas.allard-f.avocat@outlook.fr
03 20 74 16 73 nolallegre@yahoo.fr
03 20 13 01 07 maloyau@capstan.fr
06 79 42 61 53 yamin@amara-avocat.fr
03 20 14 93 43 namghar.avocat@gmail.com
03 28 52 95 00 amourelle.avocat@gmail.com
07 56 95 80 48 louizaamrane.avocat@yahoo.com
03 28 66 81 74 cabinet@dsa-avocats.fr
```

... so on

Comment: can you tell me the css selector that only get telephone value I try that `.contact[p="Tél."]` but not work for me

Comment: I donot like split method to replace fax number

Comment: @Amin Aziz, use:`tel=soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Tél.")').text.replace('Tél.', '').strip()`

Comment: I try that Then I tell you

Comment: they give me the fax number also the css selector not work for me

Comment: you have any solution for these?

Comment: It's working: `tel=soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Tél.")').next_element.replace('Tél.', '').strip()`

Comment: If I made css selector for fax `p:-soup-contains("Fax")` so these is correct

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `select()` that will give you a `ResultSet` use `select_one()` to get the first / a single element:

```
soup.select_one('.address+ .contact p').text
```

Else iterate the `ResultSet` or pick element by index.

```
soup.select('.address+ .contact p')[0].text
```

---

#### EDIT

Based on your comment, there are different approaches to get the goal.
Note: All these uses [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) that needs python >= 3.8 to shorten the lines, else use normal if statements.

Regex:
Best in my opinion, if you do not know if tel or fax ist first element.

```
import re

t.group(1) if (t:=re.search('Tél. ([\d\s]*)', soup.select_one('.address+ .contact p').text)) else None
```

Slicing:
Only if tel is first element.

```
t.contents[0][5:] if (t:=soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Tél")')) else None
```

Replacing:
Only if tel is first element.

```
t.contents[0].replace('Tél.','').strip() if (t:=soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Tél")')) else None
```

Comment: If I made css selector for fax p:-soup-contains("Fax") so that it is correct?

Comment: The selector is correct, but you have to filter / handle the result in another way. better try to go with `t.group(1) if (t:=re.search('Fax ([\d\s]*)', soup.select_one('.address+ .contact p').text)) else None` while pattern in html have inconsistences.
`

Comment: they print empty  in fax number

Comment: While it becomes a chat, this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus, to keep the answer clean - Hint: Ask your self, is there always a fax, if there is no fax what do you expect should it print?

Comment: I have ask new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416956/trying-to-get-fax-number-using-beautifulsoup can you answer it?